# I am getting Mixed Content Error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have installed a fresh wordpress on my server my root domain is already pointing to a folder so i created another folder under root with blog now rootdomain/blog points to wordpress site. But while installation page i was getting mixed content error and my css was not properly rendering SSL is installed on server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYpmz.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that some of those CSS resources are being called using the insecure http, while the page is being loaded using https.

If the issue is in the database, the [Velvet Blues](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin will resolve it quickly and easily. Just search for:

```
http://dev.401kplans.com
```

and replace with:

```
https://dev.401kplans.com
```

I find that this plugin fixes 99% of the mixed content issues I encounter. For some reason, it doesn't find links in Theme Options and Widgets.

Of course, ensure you are using https in your Settings.

However, if this doesn't resolve the issue, it could be that those files are hard-coded in your functions.php file or similar. If they aren't fixed using the plugin, I grep through the themes and plugins folder looking for the insecure domain:

```
grep -r "http://dev.401kplans.com" *
```